# How can I enable PHP Extension intl in an Apache server?

Tags: php, windows, apache, intl

I have removed the starting semicolon ( ; ) from php.ini the following code.

`;extension=php_intl.dll`

[Screenshot: php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr8PC.png)

And everything seems fine when I runs

`php -m`

[Screenshot: cmd.exe. Looks like intl has been loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LUeK.png)

But in the website powered by Apache, the extension intl simply disappeared when I opens a website with source code below:

`<?php`

`phpinfo();`

`?>`

[ScreenShot: intl disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG0MV.png)

Meanwhile, extension mbstring can be seen in both direction.
I'm wondering how to load intl correctly. Please help me.

Note:
Operating system: Windows 10
Apache: httpd-2.4.54-o111s-x64-vs16
PHP: php-8.2.0-Win32-vs16-x64

I have tried:

1. copy php_intl.dll to Apache24/bin or Windows/SysWOW64
2. reinstall Visual C++ 2019 Redistributed
3. check httpd.conf and php.ini again

httpd.conf

`LoadModule php_module modules/php-8.2.0-Win32-vs16-x64/php8apache2_4.dll`

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm`

`PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache24/modules/php-8.2.0-Win32-vs16-x64/"`

php.ini

`extension=intl`

Comment: have you restarted Apache after changing php.ini?

Comment: Change `extension=intl` to `extension=php_intl.dll` , re-start apache and then see the result

Comment: Also keep in mind that the CLI version and the apache module version of php have separate `php.ini` files.

Comment: I have restarted Apache after changing php.ini. 
Changed `extension=intl` to `extension=php_intl.dll` and restarted Apache, but `php -m` and `phpinfo()` still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied icu****.dll from PHP folder to Apache24/bin folder and everything looks fine now.